# A way to start an Electron.js app when another windows app launches?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I am a junior developer that started working in Electron about 4 weeks ago and I would like for my app to start when I start another app (unrelated to Electron).

My idea so far is to launch the app without rendering anything on Windows startup and somehow listen for it with https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/desktop-capturer#desktopcapturergetsourcesoptions. I don't know if this will work as I have not tried this yet.

As you can see, this is not exactly what I want so I'm wondering if there's a way for Electron start the app when another app is launched.

I must mention that I will undertake this task later in my project but I want to have a perspective and some expectations regarding the difficulty of it.

I appreciate any kind of tips!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest launching your app on startup ( Only trayicon )

Then setup a watcher and use tasklist to check if the app you're looking for is running.
https://github.com/sindresorhus/tasklist#readme

Use ipcMain to open your App Window.

Comment: You massively improved my idea! I love tasklist! Will try it and let you know what came out of it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could just add a .bat file to the startup directory in windows, and have the .bat file start two programs.  However, that may or may not trigger after windows is done loading entirely.

You may be able to attach a .bat file that launches one or more programs and attach that to your listener.

Comment: Interesting approach! My app will be installed on various machines I have little or no access too, so I need to make it work right off the bat. I will investigate to see if the app install that .bat file when the user installs the app. Thank you!